# How to catch Android WebView HTTP 500 error code covering all Android versions (4 - 7)

Tags: android, http, webview, error-handling

I have an android WebView set up with a WebViewClient as suggested by other threads to cover e.G. a 500 HTTP error from android 6 and above by using onHttpErrorReceived as follows:

```
  webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.d("FREEBROWSER", "----------------- ERROR deprecated ---------------");
            }

            @Override
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                Log.d("FREEBROWSER", "----------------- ERROR " + rerr.getDescription() + " ---------------");
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }

            @Override
            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
                onReceivedError(view, errorResponse.getStatusCode(), errorResponse.getReasonPhrase(), request.getUrl().toString());
            }
        });
```

This works perfectly fine for devices running API level 23 and above (as it was also mentioned by the docs and other threads here, but this is of course unsatisfying if you want to catch a 500 error also for devices below API Level 23.

I get absolutely NO error callback with my android 4.4.2 device. Neither the version

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
```

nor the version

```
 public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr)
```

is beeing called on a 500 error.

By looking at possible solutions for devices lower than API 23 I basically found 2 solutions in many variants (I don't want to explain them here again):

1. Catch  "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" and/or other callbacks and perform a kind of "HEAD" request in advance to see if the webpage is reachable or not, then display custom error page.
2. Use JavaScript injection and ajax to determine reachability

Also as far as i could read there are no plans to release a supportlib version of this callback so that it could be used in older versions.

---

**My question is: Are there other clean ways to support catching HTTP error status codes with devices running Android versions lower than API Level 23? Has anybody implemented a suitable solution for customers which at best exclude an additional request or JavaScript injection?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to download HTML String and check the response header with this initial request. Use e.g. HttpURLConnection (or OkHttpClient) to do that. There you can check response with  HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(). If response code is good for you, load downloaded string with WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(), see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: **Thank you for your answer. this solution will effectively limit the number of requests to just one :-)** Additionally i suggested to limit using this method to devices < android 6.0 and fall back to the new onHttpErrorReceived(...) stuff of API 23 and above. Also i hope we are able to convince the customer to have only a limited "list" of URL's which will manually be loaded in shouldOverrideUrlLoading(...)

Comment: "Thank you for your answer. this solution will effectively limit the number of requests to just one" You are welcome. The WebView requests all other resources (e.g. CSS, Javascript) by itself as a normal browser would do. So, it is not  only one request ;-)